# Passing Username to Router Parameters

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

So I'd like to create a user profile listing the posts a user has made. My problem is passing each username through the router and onto Meteor.publish/subscribe. I keep getting "username undefined"

I suppose my question is: how does Iron Router know what "this.params.username" are? Should the url provide that?

Router

```
Router.route('userProfile',{
   path: '/:username',
   waitOn: function () {
     return Meteor.subscribe('userprofile', this.params.username)},
   data: function () {return {posts:Posts.find({username: this.params.username})};},
});
```

Meteor.publish

```
Meteor.publish('userprofile', function () {
  return Posts.find({username: this.params.username});
});
```

Template

```
<template name="userProfile">
 <div class="posts">
  {{#each posts}}
   {{> postItem}}
  {{/each}}
 </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routing code is correct, if you `console.log` the username inside `waitOn` or `data` you should get the correct value.

```
Router.route('userProfile', {
  path: '/:username',
  waitOn: function () {
    console.log('waitOn', this.params.username);
    return Meteor.subscribe('userprofile', this.params.username);
  },
  data: function () {
    console.log('data', this.params.username);
    return {
      posts: Posts.find({username: this.params.username})
    };
  }
});
```

However, the way you fetch the parameter inside your publish function is wrong, you should rewrite your publication like this :

```
Meteor.publish('userprofile', function (username) {
  return Posts.find({username: username});
});
```

The arguments you send to `Meteor.subscribe` after the name of the publication are passed to the publish function as parameters.